# How do I get Clojure maro to output the original code without substitutions?

Tags: clojure

There is macros. This macro is convenient because it allows you
to see the result of executing the Clojure script.
But often it gives out a result that does not suit me.
I use Babashka for running scripts.

```
(defn symbol-several
  "returns a symbol with the concatenation of the str values of the args"
  [& x]
  (symbol (apply str x)))

(defmacro ! [& forms]
  (cons
   `symbol-several
   (for [form forms]
     `(str '~form " ;-> " ~form "\n"))))
```

,that outputs:

```
c:\clj>bb "~@.clj"
(do (def v [3 4]) (def l (quote (1 2))) (clojure.core/sequence (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list 0) l v)))) ;-> (0 1 2 3 4)
```

The ~@.clj file contains the macro "!" and the code:

```
"(! (do (def v [3 4]) (def l '(1 2)) `(0 ~@l ~@v)))"
```

How to rewrite a macro so that it outputs the original code, i.e. something like this:

```
(do (def v [3 4]) (def l '(1 2)) `(0 ~@l ~@v))) ;-> (0 1 2 3 4)
```

Also, instead of the result (list), the macro outputs LazySeq:

```
c:\clj>bb map.clj 
(apply map vector [[1 2] [3 4]]) ;-> clojure.lang.LazySeq@8041
```

I use Babashka (bb.exe) for running script.
The map.clj file contains the macro "!" and the code:

```
(apply map vector [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

Comment: Wild guess: [Lazy seqs do not print readably](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJ-2647)

Comment: I didn't understand this:

Как переписать макрос, чтобы он выводил изначальный код, т.е. что-то вроде этого:

Can you translate it and give a brief formulation of the question you would like an answer to?

E.g. given this input, how do I get that output?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pr-str` helps printing Clojure data structures properly.

```
(defn symbol-several
  "returns a symbol with the concatenation of the str values of the args"
  [& x]
  (symbol (apply str x)))

(defmacro ! [& forms]
  `(symbol-several
    ~@(for [form forms]
        `(str '~form " ;-> " (pr-str ~form) "\n"))))

(! (apply map vector [[1 2] [3 4]]))

;; => (apply map vector [[1 2] [3 4]]) ;-> ([1 3] [2 4])
```

Also see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pr-str